# FileMaker Pro - Connect 3 tables

Tags: sql, filemaker

I have this 3 tables (USR-User Data Entry table, ITR-Retail Transaction table and SJ-Sales Journal table).

[image]

So my problem is I can't get the right relationship connection between this 3 tables on how to update the record on the SJ table. The first connection is good but it only update the record on the ITR table. Is it possible to update two tables (ITR and SJ) on the same time with the same ID (record).

Comment: I hope, you are not using brackets in your actual table or table occurrences names - this is allowed by FileMaker but is very bad practice

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that a user could have multiple retail transaction, so the first relationship between USR and ITR should be USR::usr_ID to ITR::itr_usrID.

I am not sure if transaction can be attached to multiple sales, but in any case your relationship should be ITR::ID to SJ::itdID.

With this set up yu will be able to update both records from the User context

Comment: "USR::usr_ID to ITR::itr_usrID then ITR::ID to SJ::itdID" , is this right sir?. .

Comment: It did'nt work sir. I tried to update a record in Retail transaction using those connection but the `SJ::balance` field didnt update.

Comment: Could be a number of reasons, but most probably the relationships are not set up correctly. Check that the foreign keys are indexed.